# How to convert the json object response from retrofit success response?

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I have worked with retrofit file upload. Here by using `system.out.println` I can track the response body. But can't convert the response to `JSON` object.
I hereby write my code. Kindly please let me know how do I parse and get the string value using retrofit success message and failure message.

### ApiConfig:

```
public interface ApiConfig {

    @Multipart
    @POST("general/Candidate/fileUpload")
    Call<ResponseBody> upload(
            @Header("Authorization") String authorization,
            @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> map,
            @Part("id") RequestBody id,
            @Part("fileCount") RequestBody fileCount,
            @Part("fileType") RequestBody fileType,
            @Part("platform") RequestBody platform,
            @Part("externalID") RequestBody externalID);


}
```

### ServiceGenerator:

```
public class ServiceGenerator {

    public static final String API_BASE_URL = "http://104.239.173.64/peoplecaddie-api/";

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;
    private static OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)

                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new Gson()));

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }

}
```

### uploadFile1:

```
private void uploadFile1(Uri fileUri) {
    progressDialog.show();
    ApiConfig service =
            ServiceGenerator.createService(ApiConfig.class);



    File file = FileUtils.getFile(this, fileUri);
    RequestBody requestFile =
            RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);
    Map<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("fileContent0\"; filename=\"" + file.getName() + "\"", requestFile);
    MultipartBody.Part body =
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("fileContent0", file.getName(), requestFile);
    String idStr = "1743";
    String fileCountStr = "1";
    String fileTypeStr = "SAMPLE";
    String platformStr = "Android";
    String externalIDStr = "portpolio";
    RequestBody idReq =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), idStr);
    RequestBody fileCountReq =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), fileCountStr);
    RequestBody fileTypeReq =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), fileTypeStr);
    RequestBody platformReq =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), platformStr);
    RequestBody externalIDReq =
            RequestBody.create(
                    MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), externalIDStr);
    // finally, execute the request
    Call<ResponseBody> call = service.upload("817b6ce98fd759e7f148b948246df6c1", map, idReq, fileCountReq, fileTypeReq, platformReq, externalIDReq);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call,
                               Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Rrespppppp--->"+response.body().string());
                Log.e("response", "response------------------>" + response.body().string());
                JSONObject profileFileUploadResponse = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response.body()));
                Log.e("retro", "retroFileResp------------------>" + profileFileUploadResponse);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Upload error:", t.getMessage());
        }
    });

}
```

Here upload file method I can track the response using. This works fine.

```
 System.out.println("Rrespppppp--->"+response.body().string());
```

But while try to convert the `JSON` Object it will not work the error code is below. And please let me know how do i parse and get the success and failure response value using this code.

```
Log.e("response", "response------------------>" + response.body().string());
JSONObject profileFileUploadResponse = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response.body()));
Log.e("retro", "retroFileResp------------------>" + profileFileUploadResponse);
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
**You have to use Gson to get JsonObject response like below.**

public interface getProfileInfo {

    @GET("users/{userid}")
    Call<JsonObject> getProfileData(@Path("userid") String userId);
}



  private void getUserProfileInfo(String userId) 
{
getProfileInfo postService=RetrofitApi.makeNetworkRequest().create(getProfileInfo.class);

        Call<JsonObject> call = postService.getProfileData(userId);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {

                System.out.println("user Info :" + response.body().getAsJsonObject());
                setUserData(response.body().getAsJsonObject());


            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                // Log error here since request failed
                System.out.println("Error :" + t.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: i will check this and let you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit Response is already in json format you can get item by

```
{ "result": [{ "fileId": 852, "status": 1, "pcData": { "id": 635, "filename": "IMG_20161122_175344.jpg", "filepath": "uploads\/peoplecaddie\/files\/1743_1480742360_IMG_20161122_‌​175344.jpg" } }] }


String fileid=response.body().getresult(0).getFileId();
String status=response.body().getresult(0).getStatus();
```

Comment: {
 "result": [{
  "fileId": 852,
  "status": 1,
  "pcData": {
   "id": 635,
   "filename": "IMG_20161122_175344.jpg",
   "filepath": "uploads\/peoplecaddie\/files\/1743_1480742360_IMG_20161122_175344.jpg"
  }
 }]
}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    this is My response how do i pars the file id, file path and path , kindly please help me solve this. @raj

Comment: check with getResult(0)

Comment: Sorry raj no more get method is there under response.body().

Answer (score 0):

Modified your code. Please try. You will get json object in **result**

```
   Call<ResponseBody> call = service.upload("817b6ce98fd759e7f148b948246df6c1", map, idReq, fileCountReq, fileTypeReq, platformReq, externalIDReq);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call,
                                   Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Rrespppppp--->"+response.body().string());
                    Log.e("response", "response------------------>" + response.body().string());
                    //JSONObject profileFileUploadResponse = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response.body()));
                    ResponseBody result = response.body();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("Upload error:", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

Comment: ResponseBody result = response.body(); is not works for me                  Even i print Log.e("result","result--->"+result); i can't track result value by using log also.

Answer (score 0):

You can only call `response.body().string()` once.  From the [`ResponseBody`](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/ResponseBody.html) docs --

> The response body can be consumed only once.

You try to consume the body on both of the following two lines

```
Log.e("response", "response------------------>" + response.body().string());
JSONObject profileFileUploadResponse = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response.body()));
```

You can read it once into a variable and reuse that --

```
final String body = response.body().string();
Log.e("response", "response------------------>" + body);
JSONObject profileFileUploadResponse = new JSONObject(body);
```

That should fix your problem, but if you don't want to go further and don't want to deal with creating the `JSONObject` yourself, one of the benefits of retrofit it does deserialization as well.  You are already configuring a gson converter to your retrofit, so you should be able to update your call to --

```
@Multipart
@POST("general/Candidate/fileUpload")
Call<ReturnObject> upload(...)
```

where `ReturnObject` is the POJO you want to deserialize to.  You will have to update your response handler as well, to expect a `ReturnObject` type.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, It will work

Change Call Type as **JsonElement**

```
@GET("LoginAPI")
Call<JsonElement> getLogin(@Query("Username") String userName,
                           @Query("Password") String password);
```

Get Json object from the response

```
public void onResponse(Call<JsonElement> call, Response<JsonElement> response) {
    try {
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response.body().toString());
        textView.setText(object.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        textView.setText(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```